# Creating a list that contains lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, expression-trees

In C#, how to create a list that can contains lambda?

something i can write:

```
//Declare list here
list.Add(model => model.Active);
list.Add(model => model.Name);
```

and later on i can access the list in view

```
@foreach(var lambda in list)
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(lambda)
@next
```

how to define this list?

**Update:**

```
List<Delegate> list = new List<Delegate>(); //Can accept every lambda expression
```

but

```
@foreach (Delegate func in dtSetting.ColumnSettings)
{
    <th width="10%">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(func) // The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly
    </th>
}
```

Comment: May be `List<Func<modelType, object>>`? Not a good idea though.

Comment: Use expression tree?

Comment: @mshsayem but the Func<object,object> is not a Func<modelType,object>

Comment: @黄天文 What do you mean, exactly? What is using `Func<object, object>`?

Comment: @LeiYang yes, i'm planning to use Expression Tree, but I struggle in defining the column setting..
how to set a property that can accept all lambda expression and then use them in view?

Answer (score 0):

`Html.DisplayNameFor` expects `Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression` parameter.

You can create a `List` of such objects of the same `TModel` type and use it:

```
// Somewhere in .cs file
public List<Expression<Func<MyModel, object>>> GetListToDisplay()
{
  var list = new List<Expression<Func<MyModel, object>>>();

  list.Add(x => x.myProperty1);
  list.Add(x => x.myProperty2);
  list.Add(x => x.myMethod());

  return list;
}

// In your View
@model MyModel  
foreach (var expr in GetListToDisplay())
{
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(expr)
}
```

Comment: I create something like that(see my Update)
but still error
 // The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Comment: @黄天文 Your code is not similar. You use `Delegate` while I am using `Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>`. Try this one and tell me, if it's not working.

Comment: Okay, seems can work in IDE, but i wonder if the MVC is smart enough to Convert the Expression<Func<MyModel, object>> to Exactly
Expression<Func<MyModel, int>> or Expression<Func<MyModel, string>> based on our actual definition

Comment: It is smart enough, but it won't change type of object, if you don't tell him to do this.

Comment: @foreach (var func in dtSetting.ColumnSettings)
{
    <th width="10%">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(func)
    </th>
}

throwing an error "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

i inpected func, the Expression.Body.NodeType become Convert and cause this error

Comment: I checked the MVC code, they only support ExpressionType ArrayIndex, Call, MemberAccess(this is what we want), and Parameter

Comment: Oh, I see. Then, you need to use something else instead of expressions . Maybe, reflection and some custom attributes like `HtmlDisplayable` :)

Answer (score 0):

Improving on @Yeldar's answer, I think you can make the list a list of `LambdaExpression`, then make your own `DisplayNameFor` that will work. I'm not so proficient with ASP.NET MVC, but this may set you down the right path:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void DisplayNameFor(this HtmlHelper html, LambdaExpression e)
    {
        if(e.Parameters.Count != 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Only lambdas of form Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> are accepted.");

        //Gather type parameters
        var valueType = e.ReturnType;
        var modelType = e.Parameters[0].Type;

        //Get method with signature DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel,TValue>>)
        var methodinfos = typeof (DisplayNameExtensions).GetMethods()
            .Where(mi => mi.Name == "DisplayNameFor")
            .ToList();
        var methodInfo = methodinfos[1];

        //Construct generic method
        var generic = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(modelType, valueType);

        //invoke constructed generic method
        generic.Invoke(null, new object[] {html, e});

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. because the need to rush the project, i use other ugly way already, but will test this if i got time.. seems will work